# How to fallback on 'all' enums if values don't match in Moshi

Tags: android, moshi

Similar to [How to fallback on a enum if values don't match in OpenAPI generator's Moshi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071108/how-to-fallback-on-a-enum-if-values-dont-match-in-openapi-generators-moshi) and [How to fallback on a enum if values don't match in OpenAPI generator's Moshi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60071108/how-to-fallback-on-a-enum-if-values-dont-match-in-openapi-generators-moshi)

How can we add a custom enum adapter for moshi to support nullable or unknown/fallback values? But do it in a way for all enums?

Other answers provide something similar to

```
.add(Gender::class.java, NullableEnumAdapter<Gender>())
```

And it works. In project we have 26 enums. It does not seem practical to do this manually like:

> ```
>     .add(GetFilteredObjectivesData.FilterReset::class.java, CustomEnumJsonAdapter.create(GetFilteredObjectivesData.FilterReset::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
>     .add(DomainData.Type::class.java, CustomEnumJsonAdapter.create(DomainData.Type::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
>     .add(DomainData.JxMode::class.java, CustomEnumJsonAdapter.create(DomainData.JxMode::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
>     .add(CommonFacility.BusinessType::class.java, CustomEnumJsonAdapter.create(CommonFacility.BusinessType::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
>     .add(CommonFacility.FacilityType::class.java, CustomEnumJsonAdapter.create(CommonFacility.FacilityType::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
>     .add(TokenData.Features::class.java, CustomEnumJsonAdapter.create(TokenData.Features::class.java).withUnknownFallback(null))
> ```

**Any way to do this for all of them? Add a custom enum adapter for all enums?**